# Build Modules Unity5

Tags: build, module, unity-game-engine

Currently building a game in Unity 5. I want to build for PC instead of WebBrowser now but Unity is currently saying "No Standalone Module loaded".

I know you need to tick modules when installing Unity but I want to be able to do it without uninstalling and reinstalling unity.
Is there anyway to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The download Assistance only give the opportunity to install the 64-bits version of Unity, not the 32-bits.
So the only option right now seems to use torrent download.
If you are a 32-bits user then it would be better for you to download the desired module and install it in 32-bit folder.